# Xcode shortcut for showing file structure

Tags: xcode, keyboard-shortcuts

Is there a shortcut in Xcode 4 for showing the file structure, like this? I know you can click on the little breadcrumb to get to it but I'm surprised there is no obvious keyboard shortcut that I can find.

On that same note, is there a shortcut to jump to a method signature in the same file? There is a global one open quickly but often it is useful to limit the scope to current file.

[image]

Answer (score 31, accepted):

Set the shortcut for this on Xcode keybindings prefs, look for "Standard Editor -> Show Document items", the default shortcut is "Control + 6" but it is in conflict with some other shortcut in the the OS X preferences, you have to change the shortcut to some else and you are ready to go, Cheers.

Comment: Oh wow, and you can type to search too while the Document Items menu is showing! Can't thank you enough! This will be a huge time saver!

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out Tony. I would have missed it. :)

Comment: I knew about ctrl-6 already but came here looking for how to do the same thing with the list of files to the left of the document items. Guess what? ctrl-5!